# php file not being found

Tags: php, html

i am writing a unit converter php program. i have the set up of the page, but it seems like my php file is not being found. when i click the submit button i am brought a an error page. this is my html code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="hw7.php" method="post">
<h2>Convert length:</h2>
<p>Select conversion direction: <br />
<input type="radio" name="dir" value="1" 

checked="checked"/> Feet to meters<br />
<input type="radio" name="dir" value="2" /> Meters to feet<br 

/>
</p>

<p>Value to be converted: <br /><input type="text" 

name="cvalue" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Convert" /></p>

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my php file

```
<?php


$fTOm = $_POST["cvalue"] * 3.2808;
$mTOf = $_POST["cvalue"] / 3.2808;


echo "Result: ";
if ($POST[ 'dir'] == "1") <?php echo "$_POST["cvalue"]; ?> feet = <?php echo "fTOm"; ?> meters;


?>
```

Comment: You sure **hw7.php** exists in the same folder as this page ?

Comment: Sos is `hw7.php` in the same directory as this script?

Comment: yes, my php is in the same folder as this page

Comment: What error are you getting? A 404?

Comment: Do you have php enabled for whatever server you are using

Comment: What happens if you try to run the script directly >> www.site.com/hw7.php

Comment: thats why. i was uploading my files just through chrome. i forgot that the server has have php enabled on it. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script is likely causing a server error due to improper coding. Check your server logs for PHP related errors, and possibly turn on error_reporting for PHP.

Within your PHP script, you have a statement of:

```
if ($POST[ 'dir'] == "1") <?php echo "$_POST["cvalue"]; ?> feet = <?php echo "fTOm"; ?> meters;
```

Since you're already in a PHP script, why are you using the `<?php echo` inline an `if` statement?? Correct this issue and try running the script by directly calling it.

Change the if line to :

```
if ($POST[ 'dir'] == "1") {
  echo $_POST["cvalue"] . "feet , " .  $fTOm . " meters";

}
```

Comment: your coding cleared up my errors. but when i run my code, it jumps straight my php page. my html page isn't being brought up at all. really what i would like to happen with my coding is for the results to be displayed right underneath my submit button. i know i'm not coding this correctly. trying to figure out how to code this

Comment: IF that is your intent, then you will need to look into using Javascript and Ajax callbacks to the PHP file. That should allow you to load the results in the HTML page without jumping to the PHP file. However, what you describe is standard and normal for such a script. Once your HTML 'submits' to the PHP script, it is in effect loading/displaying the PHP page.

Comment: but my html page is not even showing up. it is only my php file that is opening up

Comment: I'm unsure of what you are attempting. However if you're loading or accessing the PHP file directly, then that is why only the PHP file will load! How are you attempting to access the HTML file?? It should not open the PHP script at all, until you hit the submit action on the form.

Comment: i am creating my program through netbeans, and i am uploading my code to my schools server which is php enabled.

Comment: i can get my html page to load now. i have to upload it through a different process. but now, i can not get my results to show up. i can only get the word result to show up. but the value that i enter in doesn't show up, and also it's conversion value does not show up as well.

Comment: actually, i figured out what i was doing wrong. i had $POST instead of $_POST. thank you for your help

Comment: Glad you got it working and where able to deduce the problem through troubleshooting. A good thanks, is an accepted answer! Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that the `hw7.php` file must be in the same directory as the `HTML` page that is calling it from a form.

I will recommend to use always relative `URLs` or the `contexT_path` when possible.

try:

```
<form action="./hw7.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this maybe it will help:

`<form action="./hw7.php" method="post">`

Also remove all those syntax errors in the php script.`<?php .... ...  ?>` can not have another `<?php` inside of it.